# How to select for observations that are null for one variable and not null for another?

Tags: mysql, select

I need to select observations from a dataset in a way that excludes rows missing certain values, but having others.  For example, I have the following variables:

A, dateA, B, dateB, C, dateC

I need to exclude rows that are not null for A, but are missing a dateA value OR are not null for B, but are missing a dateB value OR are not null for C but are missing a dateC value. Also, because my variables are structured so that they can be empty values, I have been using the following to code to identify "null" observations:

```
WHERE dateA > '';
```

I'm not sure what to put in my select statement to accomplish this.  Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT here would be some example data: (sorry for the awkward formatting)

**Obs**----**A**-----**dateA**

1--------3-----2002-02-13 00:00:00

2--------8-----2009-12-19 00:00:00

3--------0

4--------7

The result I would want would be to select observations 1, 2, and 3, but not 4 because it is missing a value for dateA, but has a value for A. 3 should be included because although it is missing a value for dateA, it has a 0 value for A. I also have other variables, B, dateB, C and dateC that need to be selected for in the same way.

Comment: Please add example data and expected output to make it clearer

Comment: `NULL` and `0` are not the same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *include* these rows we would do:

```
WHERE (A IS NOT NULL AND A != 0 AND dateA > '') 
       OR (B IS NOT NULL AND B != 0 AND dateB > '') 
       OR (C IS NOT NULL AND C != 0 AND dateC > '');
```

To exclude these we can simply use NOT:

```
WHERE NOT(
          (A IS NOT NULL AND A != 0 AND dateA > '') 
          OR (B IS NOT NULL AND B != 0 AND dateB > '') 
          OR (C IS NOT NULL AND C != 0 AND dateC > '')
      );
```

Edit: Update following question clarification.

Comment: Your second query is not the inverse of the first.. you'd need to change the `OR`s to `AND`s.

Comment: @Arth That would only then exclude rows for which *all* of those clauses were true. I don't believe this is what the asker wants. `NOT (P)` is the inverse of `(P)`.

Comment: I just included sample data to hopefully make this question a little more clear.

Comment: @Jim You are correct, my apologies.. totally confused!

Comment: @Jim you do not need the `IS NOT NULL` as `!=` will return `NULL` for a `NULL` record

Comment: @Jim, thanks for your help! I just tried your suggestion and received the following error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near WHERE NOT(
          (A IS NOT NULL AND A !=

Answer (score 0):

Is this the badger?

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1
 WHERE (a>0 AND dateA > '')
    OR (b>0 AND dateB > '')
    OR (c>0 AND dateC > '');
```

or this?

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1
 WHERE (a=0 OR (a>0 AND dateA>''))
   AND (b=0 OR (b>0 AND dateB>''))
   AND (c=0 OR (c>0 AND dateC>''));
```